# QGraphicsItem - Follow the mouse cursor

Tags: qt, animation, sprite, qgraphicsitem, mouse-cursor

I'm stuck on how to approach this. I have a QGraphicsItem within a scene, and I'm passing a hover event from the scene to this child. While the move event occurs (I'm just using mouseMoveEvent with mouse tracking on), I want another QGraphicsItem to follow the cursor.

I don't need any collision detection, drag and drop, etc. Just an item that follows the cursor. The only two ways I can think of are...

1. While the mouse moves, draw a new QGraphicsItem at the mouse position. I would need to clear the scene, redraw everything, and draw the new position on top.
2. Somehow use the animation framework and whenever the mouse moves, animate the QGraphicsItem to move to the new mouse position in 1 millisecond.

I'm probably either overthinking this or unaware of another way to do this... any suggestions?

Comment: Just to maybe clarify a bit better - essentially I'm making a tooltip out of a QGraphicsItem that fires (and follows the cursor) while hovering over another QGraphicsItem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it like this

1. Create the GraphicsItem `cursor` which will be moved with mouse-cursor, and store its pointer somewhere (in scene subclass for instance. I have a toolset, so for me it's in one of these tools)
2. Set its Z-Value (`QGraphicsItem::setZValue`) so that the cursor will be painted above all other items in your scene
3. Track `QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent` events, forward these events down to the `cursor` pointer, and update item's position

that's it.
I guess it corresponds to your solution 1, except you don't have to clear the scene thanks to z-value feature.

Comment: Ah.. perfect. Let me give this a try.

Comment: So I tried this, but what's weird is it will only draw in a certain area. It's like from 0,0 to 30something,20something, it will not paint. Then after that, area, it will. But then once it hits 100something,100something, anything out of that bounds, it won't paint. But then if I resize the window, it paints to that last spot the custor registered at. Any ideas..?

Comment: @chrometix now this looks like a problem of item's `boundingRect` and/or scene's rect, which is a different issue. Is your initial issue solved, regardless the update area problems ?

Comment: To an extent, yeah. Painting the item on move also causes the issue of remnants of the item staying painted if the cursor moves too fast. I may look into another way of doing this.. maybe just fall back to stationary tooltips, Ill have to tinker around a bit more. Thanks for the guidance though, much appreciated

Comment: Just for future reference - I'm taking an entirely different direction. Saving the QGraphicsItem to a QImage, and building a QPixMap that the cursor can use.